# FFmpeg. How do I merge videos into multiple files?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have a lot of videos that are 5 seconds long. How do I use ffmpeg to merge them into 15-second videos? That is, all 5-second videos should be joined together three by three into one file.
For example: I have 30 videos of 5 seconds, the output should be 10 videos of 15 seconds.
Need to implement this with one script, without additional manipulation, as much automation as possible without manual labor.

Comment: I think your question could be separated into multiple tasks. Try them one by one and return if you have any errors.

Answer (score 0):

you can use concatenate, https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate

its very simple to use if you define a list of files as explained in the link